# Check if ID equals

Tags: jquery

I need to remove a class from all table cells when an element's parent has a particular ID.

```
$(".closethis").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this).parent().parent();
    if ($this.attr("id") == "mainArea") {
        $("#myTbl").removeClass("myClass");
    }
});
```

I do need to check for ID because this is part of a function and if ID is not equal to this value it is probably for another case.

Looks right but it does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: You'd better give a demo. And what do you mean by `$("#.myTbl")`, is it a typo?

Comment: Please post your HTML aswell. This doesn't look right: `$("#.myTbl")` Probably $("#myTbl td")?

Comment: If you need an element's parent why are you doing parent().parent()?  If you posted some html, or better yet created a jsFiddle, it would help.

Comment: @xdazz Good catch. Typo.

Comment: Plain Ol' JavaScript: `this.id === 'mainArea'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hmm.. Ok.. $var looks like PHP.. i'd just call it was it is. Also, you have #. in your myTbl which means id and class.... so it depends on how you are identifying the cells.. but assuming the cells are td's inside a table ID'd "myTbl", try this

```
$(".closethis").click(function(){
    var checkDiv = $(this).parent().parent();
    if (checkDiv.attr("id") == "mainArea") {
        $("#myTbl").find('td').removeClass("myClass");
    }
});
```

If you can't make that work, give us the ID's or class's of each element and we can give you the correct code.

Comment: Putting `$` in front of a variable is a convention some use to designate a variable holding a jQuery object. It has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 14):

Try using the `is` function present in jQuery.

```
if ($this.is('#mainArea')) { ... }
```